# how to select with if statement by peewee

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I am getting all categories and join category table with item_category which has post categories.
my sql is like that

```
SELECT category.*,IF(item_category.category_id=NULL, 0,1) is_selected
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN item_category ON category.category_id=item_category.category_id AND item_id=1
```

i tried that but it did not work. because python throw error when use if

```
Category.select(Category, ItemCategory, fn.if(ItemCategory.category_id==None, 0, 1) )
```

what is the correct usage for if statement?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found a solution but i do not know it is best way.
i changed 'fn.if' to 'fn.IF' and it worked

```
Category.select(Category, ItemCategory, fn.IF(ItemCategory.category_id==None, 0, 1) )
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `IF`, but you can also use `case`. For details, check out the case docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#case

Comment: @coleifer thanks. you can find about information "mysql if" there http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Case` function to get the required output as like `IF`/`ELSE` (following peewee official code source https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/853d57005d0dbc49a0ff24560531c637ceeb4f25/peewee.py#L1732)

```
from peewee import Case

Category.select(
    Category,
    ItemCategory,
    Case(None, [((ItemCategory.category_id==None), 0)], 1)
)
```

here, parameters of `Case` are -

- 1st parameter: `predicate` default is `CASE`
- 2nd parameter: `expression_tuples` which contains condition`(ItemCategory.category_id==None)` and condition passed value `0`
- 3rd parameter: ELSE value (`1`)

Comment: In peewee>=3.14 I had to alias the `Case` object for this solution to work, ie: `Case(...).alias('new_col')`